# Empathy Chat: People Nearby text chat OK but file transfer fails. Why? How to troubleshoot?

Tags: empathy, file-sharing, nfs

### Problem:

Chat works (sending text and smileys) with the "People Nearby" feature but sending files silently fails. Going to Contact > Send File presents the sender with a file chooser and no error is displayed. Neither the sender or receiver sees anything change after the sender selects the file and hits 'send'. Any idea why?

### Our Setup:

We have a lan with mostly Ubuntu 12 clients. Home directories are exported from a Ubuntu server and authentication is managed with LDAP. I can see other users in the Contact List window of Empathy and each one is showing twice. All the computers are on the same subnet and get their IP addresses via DHCP. They are assigned the same addresses in the DHCP conf with 'fixed address' declarations tied to mac addresses and the IPs are forward and reverse lookup-able by either hostame or FQDN.

```
#etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search xx.xx.com #our domain
```

### Update:

If the file transfer is initiated from Contacts List window by highlighting the desired recipient, choosing  Edit > Contact > Send File, the desired behavior occurs. Namely, a transfer progress window opens and informs the user the recipient has to accept the transfer. Behavior on the other end works almost as expected except that I saw briefly a ***third*** instance of sender's contact appeared in the Contact List window.
What does not work, strangely is initiating the same action from an existing Chat window by choosing Contact > Send File. Same recipient, same file.

Comment: From @Majik *"If it works in one part of the application but not in another that sounds like a bug. Have you opened a bug report?"*

Comment: These type of file transfer empathy bugs are there for a decade in Bugzilla.It used to work in Ubuntu 10.10, 11.04. After that it never really worked!.

Comment: Have you run the empathy-debugger to capture messages which could be relevant?

Comment: This appears to be a long standing bug. See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/telepathy-haze/+bug/453884